# CSV to Folium HeatMap

Tags: python, folium

I have a csv that contains numerous different Lat Longs in the exact format shown: 
`39.360611,-74.431877`

Running the following code:

```
import csv
from folium import plugins

heatmap_map = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

with open('geolocation.csv', "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [[row[0], row[1]] for row in reader]
    print(data)

hm = plugins.HeatMap(data)
heatmap_map.add_children(hm)
f.close()

heatmap_map.save("heatmap.html")
```

Gives me the following Output

```
[['39.360611', '-74.431877']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dge\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\utilities.py", line 59, in validate_location
    float(coord)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\heat.py", line 12, in <module>
    hm = plugins.HeatMap(data)
  File "C:\Users\dge\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\plugins\heat_map.py", line 67, in __init__
    for line in data]
  File "C:\Users\dge\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\plugins\heat_map.py", line 67, in <listcomp>
    for line in data]
  File "C:\Users\dge\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\utilities.py", line 63, in validate_location
    .format(coord, type(coord)))
ValueError: Location should consist of two numerical values, but '-' of type <class 'str'> is not convertible to float.
```

It seems as though python is recognizing the - symbol as a string rather than piece of negative number

Comment: Could you parse the values yourself before passing them to `HeatMap` ?

Comment: How would I parse them? I know the second value is always negative and the first is always positive

Comment: I meant just calling `float()` explicitly.

Comment: So do something along the lines of  ```data = [[row[0], float(row[1])] for row in reader]```

Comment: Personally I would do: `[(float(elem_1), float(elem_2)) for elem_1, elem_2 in reader]` It's quite similar, obviously.

Comment: Sadly that gives a similar error ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'```

Comment: Ah that's too bad, the issue must be specific to the library/function.

Comment: Thanks for the help I ended up fixing it with Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting various things, I found a Pandas Dataframe to be the best way to get the Data from CSV to heatmap. The Code looks like the following:

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
heatmap_map = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

with open(r'geolocation.csv', "r") as f:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(f),ignore_index = True)
    df = df.dropna()

hm = plugins.HeatMap(df)
heatmap_map.add_child(hm)
f.close()

heatmap_map.save("heatmap.html")
```

Notice the `dropna` as for some reason it always had a blank line entered at the end and this solved the issues that would be hit when passing such information to the heatmap